# How can I add more than 15 series to a twoway legend in Stata?

Tags: stata

I have many series on a `twoway` plot in Stata; I want to include more than 15. This graph is mainly for myself, so that I can understand what the dataset looks like. I would probably reduce the number of series for future readers, but for now, I want the detail. It is a stacked area graph. However, the legend has not printed the colours for more than 15 of the series. Can you help me to figure out how to print more colours?

```
    local counter=1
foreach occupnum in $modaloccs {
    gen occup`counter'temp=.
    replace occup`counter'temp=yearpercent if other==`occupnum'
    by year: egen occupation`counter' = min(occup`counter'temp)
    drop occup`counter'temp
    local occupationtype : label other `occupnum'
    lab var occupation`counter' "`occupationtype'"

    local ++counter
}
local nummodaloccs = `counter' -1
di `nummodaloccs'

gen sum2 = occupation1 + occupation2
forvalues blah = 3/`nummodaloccs'   {
    local blah_ = `blah' - 1
    egen sum`blah' = rowtotal(sum`blah_' occupation`blah')
    local occupationtype : variable label occupation`blah'
    lab var sum`blah' "`occupationtype'"
}
#delimit ;
twoway area occupation1 year || rarea occupation1 sum2 year || rarea sum2 sum3 year || rarea sum3 sum4 year || rarea sum4 sum5 year || rarea sum5 sum6 year || rarea sum6 sum7 year || rarea sum7 sum8 year || rarea sum8 sum9 year || rarea sum9 sum10 year || rarea sum10 sum11 year || rarea sum11 sum12 year || rarea sum12 sum13 year || rarea sum13 sum14 year || rarea sum14 sum15 year || rarea sum15 sum16 year || rarea sum16 sum17 year || rarea sum17 sum18 year || rarea sum18 sum19 year || rarea sum19 sum20 year || rarea sum20 sum21 year || rarea sum21 sum22 year || rarea sum22 sum23 year || rarea sum23 sum24 year || rarea sum24 sum25 year || rarea sum25 sum26 year || rarea sum26 sum27 year,  name(twodigitoccsdist_time, replace)
legend(order(
    27  "11 Legislators and senior officers"
    26  "12 Corporate managers"
    25  "13 General managers"
    24  "21 Physical, mathematical and engineering science professionals"
    23  "22 Life science and health professionals"
    22  "23 Teaching professionals"
    21  "24 Other professionals"
    20  "31 Natural science and engineering associate professionals"
    19  "32 Life science and health associate professionals"
    18  "33 Teaching associate professionals"
    17  "34 Other associate professionals"
    16  "41 Office clerks"
    15  "42 Customer service clerks"
    14  "51 Personal and protective services"
    13  "52 Models, salespersons and demonstrators"
    12  "61 Market-orientated skilled agricultural and fishery workers"
    11  "71 Extraction and building trades workers"
    10  "72 Metal and machinery workers"
    9   "73 Handicraft and printing workers"
    8   "74 Other craft workers"
    7   "81 Stationary-plant and related operators"
    6   "82 Machine operators and assemblers"
    5   "83 Drivers and mobile-plant operators"
    4   "91 Elementary sales and services"
    3   "92 Agricultural and fishery labourers"
    2   "93 Labourers in mining, construction, manufacturing and transport"
    1   "Other"
    )   // https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1558062-how-can-i-increase-the-number-of-characters-on-axis-labels-on-a-graph
pos(3) col(1) size(small)) ylabel(, angle(horizontal) format(%2.1f)) xtitle("") note(" " "Source: PALMS")  ytitle("Proportion of workers", margin(small)) title("Distribution of occupations in the South African labour force over time", size(medlarge) span margin(small)) xsize(15) ysize(8); // graphregion(margin(small))
#delimit cr
```

[`dataex year other yearpercent`](https://pastebin.com/5NJrBFqS)

[image: Many series in a twoway plot]

Comment: I think you've stumbled across the default number of colours supplied by default in your version of Stata (< 16?).  At best you need to specify all of the other colours wanted.

Comment: Thank you Nick. https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vwr2.png